# Variance lower bound for natural exponential family

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Let $Q$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $$Q_h(dy) = e^{y \cdot h} Q(dy) / M(h)  \quad \text{where} \quad M(h) = \int e^{y \cdot h} Q(dy)$$ defined for $h \in (-c,\infty)$ with some $c > 0$. Let $Y_h \sim Q_h$ and $V(h) := EY_h^2 - (EY_h)^2$. Then, does it follow that $$\exists c' > 0,\ h_0 > -c\ \text{ s.t. }\ \forall h \geq h_0,\ V(h) \geq e^{-c' h} \text{?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired result obviously fails to hold if the probability measure $Q$ is degenerate, that is, supported on a singleton set. Indeed, then $V(h)=0$ for all $h$.

It is much harder to construct a counterexample with a non-degenerate $Q$. The idea of such a counterexample, given below, is to make the distribution $Q$ highly lacunary, in order to make the tilted distribution $Q_h$ very close to a degenerate one, for large $h$.

Indeed, let
\begin{equation*}
    Q:=\sum_{i\ge1}p_i\delta_{2^i},
\end{equation*}
where $\delta_a$ is the Dirac distribution supported on the set $\{a\}$, $p_i:=Ce^{-4^i}$, and $C$ is the normalizing constant. Then
\begin{equation*}
    V(h)=\frac IJ, \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    I:=I(h):=\frac12\sum_{i,j\ge1}(2^j-2^i)^2z_i(h)z_j(h) \\ 
    \le S:=S(h):=\sum_{1\le i<j}4^j z_i(h)z_j(h), \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 J:=J(h):=M(h)^2=\Big(\sum_{i\ge1}z_i(h)\Big)^2, \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}
    z_i(h):=e^{h2^i}p_i.
\end{equation*}

For large natural $k$, let now
\begin{equation*}
    h=h_k:=2^{k+1}, \tag{35}\label{35}
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    z_i(h_k)=y_i:=y_{k,i}:=C\exp(2^{k+1+i}-4^i). 
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}=\exp(2^{k+i}(2-3\times2^{i-k})) \\ \le\exp(-2^{k+i})\le\exp(-2^{i+1})   
    \text{ for natural $i\ge k$} \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}\ge\exp(2^{k-1+i})\ge1  \\
    \text{ for natural $i<k$.} \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
In particular, \eqref{30} and \eqref{40} imply
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{y_{k+1}}{y_k}\le\exp(-4^k)\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{y_k}{y_{k-1}}\ge\exp(4^{k-1}).  \tag{60}\label{60}  
\end{equation*}

Now recall \eqref{20} and write
\begin{equation*}
    S=S_1+S_2+S_3, \tag{70}\label{70}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    S_1:=\sum_{i,j\colon k\le i<j}4^jy_iy_j, \quad 
    S_2:=\sum_{i,j\colon 1\le i<j\le k}4^jy_iy_j, \quad 
    S_3:=\sum_{i,j\colon i<k<j}4^jy_iy_j.  
\end{equation*}
In view of \eqref{40}, \eqref{50}, and \eqref{60},
\begin{equation*}
    S_1\le c_1y_ky_{k+1}\le c_1 e^{-4^k}y_k^2, 
\end{equation*}
where $c_1:=1+\sum_{j\ge1}j4^j e^{-2^j}\in(0,\infty)$;
\begin{equation*}
    S_2\le k^2 4^k y_{k-1}y_k\le k^2 4^k e^{-4^{k-1}}y_k^2\le e^{-4^{k-2}}y_k^2, 
\end{equation*}
since $k$ is large;
\begin{equation*}
    S_3\le c_2 k y_{k-1}y_k\le e^{-4^{k-2}}y_k^2, 
\end{equation*}
where $c_2:=\sum_{j\ge1}4^j e^{-2^j}\in(0,\infty)$.

So, by \eqref{20} and \eqref{70},
\begin{equation*}
    I\le e^{-4^{k-3}}y_k^2.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, clearly, $J\ge y_k^2$. Thus, recalling \eqref{35},
\begin{equation*}
    V(h)=V(h_k)\le e^{-4^{k-3}}<e^{-c'2^{k+1}}=e^{-c'h_k}
\end{equation*}
for any real $c'>0$ and all large enough $k$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks so much. I need to find a little time to work through this, and I'll accept once I do! PS: big fan of your papers.